# UITableView reorder like Clear app

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview

How to start moving after the long tap detect? long tap detect with uilongpressgesturerecognizer.
My code:

```
`- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    flMoveRow = NO;
    [self setEditing:YES animated:YES];
    [listView reloadData];
}


- (void)longTapGesture:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer *)sender{
    if((sender.state != UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded)&&(!flMoveRow)){
        NSLog(@"==longTapGesture:");
        flMoveRow = YES;  
        [listView beginUpdates];
        NSArray *indexPaths = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:indexPath, nil];
        [listView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:indexPaths withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
        [listView endUpdates];
        sender.enabled = NO;
    return;    
}

- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canMoveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    NSLog(@"==canMoveRowAtIndexPath:%i -- %d", indexPath.row, (int)flMoveRow);
return flMoveRow;}`
```

break touch. Thanks.

Answer (score 19):

There is a control available on cocoacontrols.com which mimics the Clear app. It is still being worked on apparently but when I downloaded it, it was still very impressive. You could either incorporate it fully in your app or use it as a starting point in your own research.

[link](http://cocoacontrols.com/platforms/ios/controls/jtgesturebasedtableviewdemo).

Comment: If it helped then it would be nice if you accepted the answer and/or marked me up! One thing is definitely true of SO and that is if you have a low accept-rate some people are put off spending the time to formulate an answer for you :-/