# Rearranging sections in the table by dragging a row up or down with drag delegate (iOS 11)

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I want to enable drag and drop in tableview. I only want to drag items in app and I don't want it to be transferred to other app.

I found two ways to implement tableview rearrangement.

### First way: use drag and drop delegate

[drag delegate documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/drag_and_drop/adopting_drag_and_drop_in_a_table_view?language=objc)
[supporting drag and drop in tableview in iOS11](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/views_and_controls/table_views/supporting_drag_and_drop_in_table_views?language=objc)

It is realy important for me not to allow drag and drop between apps.

**Is using drag delegate ok in this situation?** 
Or should I use another solution?

// didLoad

```
[self.myTableView setDragDelegate: self];
[self.myTableView setDragInteractionEnabled: YES];
```

// itemsForBeginningDragSession

```
(NSArray<UIDragItem *> *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
                itemsForBeginningDragSession:(id<UIDragSession>)session
                                 atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath  API_AVAILABLE(ios(11.0)) {
Model *model = self.listOfX[indexPath.section];

NSItemProvider *itemProvider = [[NSItemProvider alloc] initWithObject: model];

UIDragItem *dragItem = [[UIDragItem alloc] initWithItemProvider: itemProvider];

return @[dragItem];
}
```

### second way: tableview edit mode

```
[self.myTableView setEditing: YES];
```

I don't want to add a button and change the table view state to editing mode. I want to enable rearrangement by long press.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Swift - Drag And Drop TableViewCell with Long Gesture Recognizer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27631128/swift-drag-and-drop-tableviewcell-with-long-gesture-recognizer)

Comment: @fishinear drag and drop delegate are new features in iOS 11, I want to find the best way to to drag and drop. with this new feature or with previous ones.

Answer (score 2):

Your first option to use the drag and drop delegate is fine. Be sure you implement the `UITableViewDragDelegate` method `- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView dragSessionIsRestrictedToDraggingApplication:(id<UIDragSession>)session` and return `YES`. This will ensure the drag and drop must occur within the same app.

Answer (score 0):

If have been using [FMMoveTable](https://github.com/FlorianMielke/FMMoveTableView) by Florian Mielke for this purpose, which works great. But he has now discontinued it, stating that you should use IOS 11 Drag & Drop functionality instead. Although I cannot see how you can restrict that to a single table.

Another possibility is to use the tutorial mentioned in [this other StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32289833/908621).