# What is PBItemCollectionServicer？

Tags: ios, objective-c

I searched SO ,find nothing about `PBItemCollectionServicer`.

My question become form my app crash(because of memory rise violently), then print:

> PBItemCollectionServicer connection disconnected.

The screen shot:

[image]

I have no idea about the `PBItemCollectionServicer`, whats mean of that?
and how does it work?
why it print here?
Is it relate to my app crash?

---

**Edit -1**

As Nir's comment, he suspect if I use the under link framework.

https://github.com/JaviSoto/iOS10-Runtime-Headers/tree/master/PrivateFrameworks/Pasteboard.framework

No , I didn't, I searched my project with no result:

[image]

Comment: @Nirav, no ,I did not?

Comment: are you using UIPasteboard anywhere in your app. I believe that `PBItemCollectionServicer.h` is related to it.

Comment: Yeah, this is what I found. Let me know if it's useful: https://github.com/JaviSoto/iOS10-Runtime-Headers/blob/master/PrivateFrameworks/Pasteboard.framework/PBItemCollectionServicer.h

Answer (score 11):

Well, I guess those annoying PBItemCollectionServicer logs appear seconds after you copied (Command+ C) something into your iOS devices or iOS simulator which is running apps via Xcode.

The "universal clipboard" service (seems to) collects strings or images to share between your own iCloud devices (Mac, iOS devices ...)

It works in Sierra & iOS 10 environment
[Check this article](http://appleinsider.com/articles/16/06/15/universal-clipboard-for-macos-sierra-ios-10-streamlines-copypaste-between-devices)

This log happens only when under simulator/iOS device while running on Xcode, I think.

I don't know why Xcode team let this somewhat should-be-hidden log displayed... for developers? But couldn't find any documentation... blah blah

Answer (score 9):

"PBItemCollectionServicer connection disconnected." also logs when using iOS 11 table view drag-and-drop and completing a drop. It's benign there, from all I've observed.

Answer (score 6):

I was receiving:

```
Console Log: "PBItemCollectionServicer connection disconnected."
```

all of a sudden while debugging an iPhone app while connected via the USB cable to my MacBook.

After a bit of searching it turned out that it was hanging for some time because of this line of code where I was clearing the pasteboard:

```
[pasteBoard setValue:@"" forPasteboardType:UIPasteboardNameGeneral];
```

After a lot of google searching without any luck I noticed that it only happens when the iPhone was connected to my Mac.

It turned out to be the shared clipboard causing the hang/delay and log message.

If you turn off "Handoff" on the iPhone (Settings/General/Handoff) and Mac (System Preferences/General/Allow Handoff) then the problem was resolved.

The problem also goes away when you disconnect the USB cable from the Mac so it doesn't affect regular use.

Comment: For the Swift,`UIPasteboard.general.setValue("", forPasteboardType: UIPasteboard.Name.general.rawValue)`

Answer (score 0):

For me, the error occurred when `PHAssetCollection fetchAssetCollectionsWithType :` called with a block predicate:

```c
PHFetchOptions *fetchOptions = PHFetchOptions.new;
// correct
fetchOptions.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"localizedTitle = %@", targetAlbumName];
// wrong
// crash with the error message "PBItemCollectionServicer connection disconnected."
//fetchOptions.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithBlock:xxx];
PHAssetCollection * assetCollection = [PHAssetCollection fetchAssetCollectionsWithType:PHAssetCollectionTypeAlbum subtype:PHAssetCollectionSubtypeAlbumRegular options:fetchOptions].firstObject;
```

Comment: It does not occur expectedly every time. So I'm not sure the root cause of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I found that when working with drag and drop this error gets cleared up when adding

```
view.addInteraction(UIDropInteraction(delegate: self))
```

to the viewDidLoad of the view you are dropping into.

Comment: I added this and then you have to add the UIDropInteractionDelegate to the view also. But still get the "error" in the log.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, this is not an answer to the question. And I failed to find one. It's just some information I think may be helpful for someone who can dig into this and find an answer.

I was tinkering with the `copy(_:)`, `cut(_:)` and `paste(_:)` functions of `UITextField`. Almost every time I did copy/cut/paste in in field, the Xcode gave this message:

```
2020-07-17 15:45:38.796510+0800 MyApp[3062:1763915] [general] Connection to daemon was invalidated
2020-07-17 15:45:54.179188+0800 MyApp[3062:1763859] PBItemCollectionServicer connection disconnected.
2020-07-17 15:46:53.097783+0800 MyApp[3062:1763859] PBItemCollectionServicer connection disconnected.
2020-07-17 15:46:57.180499+0800 MyApp[3062:1763859] PBItemCollectionServicer connection disconnected.
2020-07-17 15:48:34.901502+0800 MyApp[3062:1764656] PBItemCollectionServicer connection disconnected.
```

The only relevant code is an extension to `UITextField`:

```
extension UITextField {
    open override func copy(_ sender: Any?) {
        print(sender)
        print(text)
    }

    open override func paste(_ sender: Any?) {
        print(sender)
        print(text)
    }
    
    open override func cut(_ sender: Any?) {
        print(sender)
        print(text)
    }
}
```

And none of them was called. How weird. Then I commented out this extension, and to my surprise, Xcode still gave the exactly same message. Anyway, after I searched here and there, I found this [in Apple Developer Forums](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/81381), which is discussion about the failure of `UIDropInteraction` with the same error message. As all the other answers mostly talked about `UIPasteboard`, I think it is necessary to put it here although it doesn't contain a solution or answer.

I tried running on both Simulator(13.5) and device(13.4.1), with Xcode 11.5, and got the same error message.

Answer (score 0):

I was also receiving a *PBItemCollectionServicer connection disconnected line* in the console log, when testing an `UICollectionViewDragDelegate` implementation.

It turned out that my **Info.plist** file didn't have that required `NSUserActivityTypes` configuration with the activity identifier of the `NSUserActivity` used in the `NSItemProvider` as part of the dragged `UIDragItem`. After fixing this, the drag-and-drop action finally worked, and the console did log the mysterious line anymore.

Answer (score 0):

In order to make sure drag-and-drop works for you,
you need to specify your type identifier (e.g. `com.xxx.TodoList.todoItem`) in `Info.plist` like this:

```
<key>UTExportedTypeDeclarations</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>UTTypeConformsTo</key>
        <array>
            <string>public.text</string>
        </array>
        <key>UTTypeDescription</key>
        <string>com.xxx.TodoList.todoItem</string>
        <key>UTTypeIconFiles</key>
        <array/>
        <key>UTTypeIdentifier</key>
        <string>com.xxx.TodoList.todoItem</string>
        <key>UTTypeTagSpecification</key>
        <dict>
            <key>public.filename-extension</key>
            <array/>
        </dict>
    </dict>
</array>
```