# Drag&Drop in CollectionView: PBItemCollectionServicer connection disconnected

Tags: swift

I'm trying to implement `Drag&Drop`. These are the methods I'm using:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, itemsForBeginning session: UIDragSession, at indexPath: IndexPath) -> [UIDragItem] {
        // This just gets the view model for the cell at that indexPath
        let rackModel = adapter.object(atSection: indexPath.section) as! RoomListData.RackModel

        // My RackModel class conforms to NSItemProviderWriting and Reading
        let itemProvider = NSItemProvider(object: rackModel)
        let dragItem = UIDragItem(itemProvider: itemProvider)
        return [dragItem]
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, itemsForAddingTo session: UIDragSession, at indexPath: IndexPath, point: CGPoint) -> [UIDragItem] {
        let rackModel = adapter.object(atSection: indexPath.section) as! RoomListData.RackModel
        let itemProvider = NSItemProvider(object: rackModel)
        let dragItem = UIDragItem(itemProvider: itemProvider)
        return [dragItem]
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, performDropWith coordinator: UICollectionViewDropCoordinator) {
    // This isn't being called  
    print("okay")
}


func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, dragPreviewParametersForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UIDragPreviewParameters? {
        let preview = UIDragPreviewParameters()
        preview.backgroundColor = .clear
        return preview
}
```

I also set `dropDelegate` and `dragDelegate` for the `UICollectionView`.
Dragging works, but when I drop the object, I get this message in the console (and the `performDrop` method is not being called):

> PBItemCollectionServicer connection disconnected

What is this? It's happening in the simulator as well as on my iPad. I can't find the problem.

Thanks for any help! Please tell me if you need to have more information. I don't know what's needed exactly to debug this.

Comment: It  looks like the logged message isn't relevant for your problem, [see this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41503275/what-is-pbitemcollectionservicer)

Comment: Hm, then there's something else wrong. I'm gonna take a look at it again

Comment: check out this project https://github.com/PrashantGaikwad11/Drag-and-Drop-Swift-API